# get user group name from a specific text in django

Tags: python, django

In django, user posts in a simple HTML form. In form, there is a field which called "technician_name". I'm getting the post with "name attribute" and write it to database.

I want additional thing: after I take the name attribute, I want to check the group of technician. Simply: I want to check user's group according to specific text.

For example: user posted the "John Doe".

```
if request.method == 'POST'    
    action_man = request.POST.get('technician_name')
```

> ```
> Output:
> action_man = "John Doe"
> ```

I need this *action_man*'s user group. The action_man's name same with username, so I can query in django auth.

*Note: I don't need the logged in user's group. I need action man's group.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. You have some String and want to filter your groups with that string?

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

some_string = "John Doe"
qs = Group.objects.filter(name=some_string)

# alternatively if only one hit is wanted
qs = Group.objects.get(name=some_string)
```

### Edit

OP writes: "[..]John Doe belongs to one group in django auth groups. I want to get that group name."

```py
user = User.objects.get(name="John Doe")
user_groups = [group.name for group in user.groups.all()]
print(f"John Doe belongs to the following groups: {user_groups}"
```

Comment: No, I want to filter "John Doe" s group name in all groups.

Comment: Do you want to filter all groups for the name "John Doe"?

Comment: No, John Doe belongs to one group in django auth groups. I want to get that group name.